# RHEL 6 DVD/CD mounting for all user

Tags: linux, rhel6

How can I mount a DVD for all user in a group in my system?

When I mount a cd/dvd using the command

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 -o ro,uid=[uid],gid=[gid] /dev/sr0 /media/DVD
```

and try ls -al, it gives

```
drwx------. 7 [user] [group] 6144 Sep 23 20:14 DVD
```

And I cannot cd into /media/DVD using a different user but whose group is [gid]

I have tried,

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 -o ro,gid=[gid] /dev/sr0 /media/DVD
sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /media/DVD
sudo mount -t iso9660 -o ro,gid=[gid],mode=0440 /dev/sr0 /media/DVD
```

Nothing works, Also a bit curious, if I don't give

```
uid=[uid]
```

the [user] in the ls -l result

```
drwx------. 7 [user] [group] 6144 Sep 23 20:14 DVD
```

is the currently logged in user who executed the command although all my commands is run using sudo and therefore I thought should be root. All other mount like drives and directory rebind is ok.

I didn't change any udev rule but my sudoer file was updated with the following

```
[user] ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

My requirement is multiple user logs in to the system and might need access to the same DVD drive in read-only mode. One person sitting at the machine mount (not necessarily as long as the command can be executed from remote,  if the media is inserted) and the others who logged in remotely uses file by going to  /media/DVD. Since it is read only they can keep the file open. Also access to DVD can be simultaneous.

Comment: Why don't you just fix the permissions of the mount point?

Comment: chmod on /media/DVD does not change anything although no error are reported